# R: Create set of variables that print all matched values in a series of column only if condition is met

Tags: r, dataframe, data-wrangling

I am trying to create a set of variables that prints out non-redundant values from another series of column if the values match the condition.

For example, my database looks something like this (but with many more columns):

```
Var_1   Var_2   Var_3
C21    S066X0A  S069X9A
I618    D06     I629
H2710   J1029   C71
S066X9D S066X9D I618
```

If a value starts with `[S][0][6][4-6]` or `[I][6]` then I would like them printed, provided that the same value has not been printed before. So the output would look like:

```
Var_1   Var_2   Var_3     Out_1    Out_2    
C21     S066X0A S069X9A  S066X0A
I618    D06     I629     I618      I629
H2710   J1029   C71
S066X9D S066X9D I618     S066X9D   I618
```

Answer (score 0):

I have taken the liberty of adding a third output column `Out_3` in order to handle the scenario where there are 3 unprinted matches in a row

```r
df <- textConnection('
Var_1,Var_2,Var_3
C21,S066X0A,S069X9A
I618,D06,I629
H2710,J1029,C71
S066X9D,S066X9D,I618
') |> 
  read.csv(header = TRUE)

df$Out_1 <- ''
df$Out_2 <- ''
df$Out_3 <- ''

lapply(seq_along(df), function(x) {
  print(df[ x, ])
  matches <- str_extract_all(df[ x, ], '^S06[4-6].*|^I6.*') |>
    unlist() |>
    na.omit() |>
    as.character()
  idx <- which((matches %in% c(df$Out_1, df$Out_2, df$Out_3)) == FALSE)
  if (length(idx) > 0) {
    matches <- matches[ idx ]
    lapply(seq_along(matches), function(i) {
      cn <- sprintf('Out_%s', i)
      df[ x, cn ] <<- matches[ i ]
    })
  }
}) |> invisible()

print(df)
```

```
    Var_1   Var_2   Var_3   Out_1   Out_2 Out_3
1     C21 S066X0A S069X9A S066X0A              
2    I618     D06    I629    I618    I629      
3   H2710   J1029     C71                      
4 S066X9D S066X9D    I618 S066X9D S066X9D
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will be way easier to deal with in a long format, as you can avoid looping over variables or needing to deal with a changing data structure and potentially lots of empty cells in the wide format.

```
longdat <- data.frame(id=seq(nrow(dat)), values=unlist(dat), row.names=NULL)
longdat <- longdat[order(longdat$id),]
##   id  values
##1   1     C21
##5   1 S066X0A
##9   1 S069X9A
##2   2    I618
##6   2     D06
##10  2    I629
##3   3   H2710
##7   3   J1029
##11  3     C71
##4   4 S066X9D
##8   4 S066X9D
##12  4    I618
```

Flagging particular values or determining uniqueness in groups is also then very straight-forward:

```
longdat$flag <- grepl("S06[4-6]|I6", longdat$values)
unique(longdat[longdat$flag,])
##       id  values flag
##Var_21  1 S066X0A TRUE
##Var_12  2    I618 TRUE
##Var_32  2    I629 TRUE
##Var_14  4 S066X9D TRUE
##Var_34  4    I618 TRUE
```

Where `dat` was:

```
dat <- read.table(text="Var_1   Var_2   Var_3
C21    S066X0A  S069X9A
I618    D06     I629
H2710   J1029   C71
S066X9D S066X9D I618", header=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Given:

```r
df <- data.frame(
  Var_1 = c("C21", "I618", "H2710", "S066X9D"),
  Var_2 = c("S066X0A", "D06", "J1029", "S066X9D"),
  Var_3 = c("S069X9A", "I629", "C71", "I618")
)

s06_ptrn <- "S06[4-6]"
i6_ptrn <- "I6"
```

Load these packages:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)
library(purrr)
library(stringr)
```

Now iterate over each row to remove duplicate values (by row) and to remove non-matching strings:

```r
out <- pmap_dfr(
  df,
  ~ {
    values <- c(...)
    
    x <- values %>%
      extract(
        !duplicated(.) &
          (str_starts(., s06_ptrn) | str_starts(., i6_ptrn))
      )
    
    # `pmap_dfr` requires that all output vectors are the same length and named:
    length(x) <- length(values)
    names(x) <- paste0("Out_", seq(length(x)))
    
    x
  }  
) %>%
  # We run this to remove empty columns:
  select(
    where(~ !all(is.na(.x)))
  )
```

And bind both dataframes:

```r
bind_cols(df, out)
```

```
#>     Var_1   Var_2   Var_3   Out_1 Out_2
#> 1     C21 S066X0A S069X9A S066X0A  <NA>
#> 2    I618     D06    I629    I618  I629
#> 3   H2710   J1029     C71    <NA>  <NA>
#> 4 S066X9D S066X9D    I618 S066X9D  I618
```